# How can I update this to do a different action when the range AR9:AR99 is selected?

Tags: excel, vba

If the target is `AR9:AR99` I would like to do another action.  Can I add it as an else if statement?  I have tried several options that have not worked as expected.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G99, W9:W99, AI9:AI99,AR9:AR99")) Is Nothing 
    Then Exit Sub
    ',V6:V25,AG6:AG25 milestone task to top 20 projects

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim NewCat As String

    Set pt = Worksheets("mPIVOTS").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Project")

    NewCat = ActiveCell

    With pt
    Field.ClearAllFilters
    Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
    pt.RefreshTable
    End With

    Worksheets("Project - Milestone Dash").Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to do something when exactly the range AR9:AR99 is selected or when any cell within the range AR9:AR99 is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like below. *(I also cleaned up your code a tiny bit by removing unnecessary with block)*

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G99, W9:W99, AI9:AI99,AR9:AR99")) Is Nothing Then

        ',V6:V25,AG6:AG25 milestone task to top 20 projects

        Dim pt As PivotTable
        Dim Field As PivotField
        Dim NewCat As String

        Set pt = Worksheets("mPIVOTS").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
        Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Project")

        NewCat = ActiveCell

        Field.ClearAllFilters
        Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
        pt.RefreshTable

        Worksheets("Project - Milestone Dash").Activate

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("AR9:AR99")) Is Nothing Then

        'do different things

    End If

End Sub
```